# LINQ-TO-SQL: add data to database without schemes and sqlmetal?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Right now i'm exploring LINQ-to-SQL using Visual Studio 2010 beta. I'm trying to understood the bascis for now, without magics light code auto generated from schemes and from sqlmetal. I have tried the following code:

```
  public class Database : DataContext
  {
    public Database( string s ) : base( s ) {}
    public Table< DUser > items;
  }

  [Table( Name = "users" )]
  public class Item
  {
    [Column]
    public string s;
  }
  // Using SQL Compact.
  var db = new Database( "Data Source=test.sdf;" );
  // Works fine and creates database.
  db.CreateDatabase();
```

But how to ADD data to database created / opened? Tutorials i have read shows something like db.Items.Add(), but Table<> don't have Add() member :(. Any insigths without using scheme / sqlmetal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `Table<T>.InsertOnSubmit` method (followed of course by DataContext.SubmitChanges).  Similarly DeleteOnSubmit for deletions.